# Determine an expression for, and minimum value of, $y=f(x)+g(x)$, where $g(x) = 4 \sin(3x)$ and $f(x) = 2 \cos(3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Need help solving this problem of finding an expression for $y=f(x)+g(x)$ if
>
> $$g(x) = 4 \sin(3x)$$
>   $$f(x) = 2 \cos(3x)$$
>
> Also determine the minimum value $y=f(x)+g(x)$ can have.

I have re-written $2\cos(3x)$ to $2\sin((\pi/2)-3x)$ but I don't know if that is what I should do.

Comment: $4\sin(3x)+2\cos (3x)$ *is* an expression. Whether or not it suits your purpose, that's another story and it largely depends on your taste in algebra. Truth to be told, some people would use that very form for this problem (not me though, because I have other preferences).

Comment: I also prefer 4sin(3x)+2cos(3x) but how can I find the minimum value of it?

Comment: That depends on how much you know of calculus.

Comment: To find the minimum value of $y$, you need to differentiate it with respect to $x$ and find those values of $x$ for which $dy/dx$ becomes zero. $y$ will attain minima/maxima at these values of $x$. This may be helpful: http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/max.htm

Answer (score 1):

Compare
$$
R\sin(A+3x)=R(\sin(A)\cos(3x)+\cos(A)\sin(3x))
$$
with your 
$$y = 2\cos(3x)+4\sin(3x)$$

From this
$$
R\sin(A)=2 \\
R\cos(A)=4
$$

1. Square and add to find $R$.
2. Divide to find $\tan(A)$ and thus $A$

This gives you an alternative expression for $y$.

The $\sin$ function varies between $-1$ and $+1$ so your new expression varies between $-R$ and $+R$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
With $\alpha=3x$
The range of expression $$a\sin\alpha+b\cos\alpha$$
Is $$[-\sqrt {a^2+b^2},\sqrt {a^2+b^2}]$$

And for solving $$\cos\alpha=2\sin\alpha$$
Try squaring both sides,  use $\sin^2\alpha=1-\cos^2\alpha$
And then reject the unwanted solutions obtained after solving the above obtained equation

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the minimum that's pretty easy since you're dealing with trig functions which produce simple derivatives...

Check out the graph on https://www.desmos.com/calculator

This sounds like a question for something for school, so they probably taught you a method for finding the minimum. Perhaps you're supposed to find the derivative and solve for ${dy\over dx}=0$?

In any case, you'll probably be expected to use whatever method they taught you.

Comment: When I derivate the expression I got -6sin(3x)+12cos(3x) = 0 Do you have any tips how I proceed

Comment: You need to combine your functions into a single trig function. Follow the process outlined by Bernard. You should end up with something like $\sqrt{4^2+2^2}\sin(3x+\arctan({2\over4}))$ if you follow his instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint*:

The standard way  consists  in noting  that if in the expression  $a\sin 3x+b\cos3 x$,   $\;;a^2+b^2=1$, we can set $\, a=\cos\varphi,\;b=\sin\varphi$ for some $\varphi$ and thus use the addition formula to rewrite the expression a $\sin(3x+\varphi)$.

Based on this observation, in the general case, we rewrite
\begin{align}
a\sin 3x+b\cos3 x&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\biggl(\underbrace{\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}_{=\,a'}\sin 3x+\underbrace{\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}_{=\,b'}\cos 3x\biggr)\\[1ex]
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(3x+\varphi),\quad\text{where}\enspace\begin{cases}\cos\varphi=a',\\\sin\varphi=b'. \end{cases}
\end{align}
This system of trigonometric equations *implies, but is *not equivalent* to $ \tan\varphi=\dfrac{b'}{a'}=\dfrac ba $. So  all we know is that
$$\varphi\equiv\arctan\frac ba\mod \pi,$$
the exact value of $\varphi \mod 2\pi$ depending on the signs o $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

You can work this out without expanding the triple angles.

Let $t(x)=4\sin3x+2\cos3x$. Now as you know, the minimum of function $t$ is $t'(x)=0$, thus:
$$\begin{align}
t(x)=4\sin3x+2\cos3x&\\
t'(x)=12\cos3x-6\sin3x&=0\\
12\cos3x&=6\sin3x\\
2\cos3x&=\sin3x\\\tag{1}
\bigl(2\cos3x&=\sin3x\bigr)^2\\
4\cos^23x&=\sin^23x\\
4\cos^23x&=1-\cos^23x\\
4\cos^23x+\cos^23x&=1\\
5\cos^23x&=1\\
\cos^23x&=\frac15\\
\end{align}$$
$$\bbox{x\Rightarrow\pm\frac13\cos^{-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac15}+2\pi K \  \mathbb{for}  \ K\in\mathbb{Z}}$$
Another way would be to note that $(1)$ can be written as:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin3x}{2\cos3x}&=1\\
\frac12\tan3x&=1\\
\tan3x&=2\\
\end{align}$$

$$\bbox{x\Rightarrow\frac13\tan^{-1}2+2\pi K\  \mathbb{for}  \ K\in\mathbb{Z}}$$
$$x\Rightarrow \frac13\biggl(-\pi+\tan^{-1}2\biggr)+2\pi K \  \mathbb{for}  \ K\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Either way, you'll get the same result.

Needless to say, the maximum and minimum values of $t(x)$ are defined by:
$$t_{max}=t\Biggl(\frac13\cos^{-1}+\sqrt{\frac15}\Biggr)=4\sin\biggl(\cos^{-1}+\sqrt{\frac15}\biggr)+2\cos\biggl(\cos^{-1}+\sqrt{\frac15}\biggr)=4.47$$
$$t_{min}=t\Biggl(-\frac13\cos^{-1}-\sqrt{-\frac15}\Biggr)=4\sin\biggl(-\cos^{-1}-\sqrt{\frac15}\biggr)+2\cos\biggl(-\cos^{-1}-\sqrt{\frac15}\biggr)=-4.47$$

Comment: I did something similar and got x as 0,37 and 0,69 but when I draw the function the minimum is -4,4 what is wrong?

Comment: I was thinking if I go the second way by using tan instead I only get one x (0,369) how do I get the second one?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the other value for $x$ using $\tan$